# Want to inject touch or tap at specified point in iDevice using js file

Tags: javascript, iphone, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I was able to launch ap in iDevice using .js file and instrument command. Javascript is as below :

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.delay(3)
var app = target.frontMostApp()
var win = app.mainWindow()
win.logElementTree();

win.tap();  
target.delay(3)
```

Using above js I'm able to launch app in iDevice but tap is located only at centre. How can I pass my own point or coordinate for tap to happen in iDevice?

Also provide a link or book that would help me in further js writing for automation related to screen shot or install/uninstall app,etc
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is the book that I used to get started: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/jptios/find.pdf

If you want to tap at different points on the window you can use the `tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:xCoord, y:yCoord}})` function. However it is not the best way necessarily to automate your app.

Take a look at the developer docs if you really want to learn!
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I got the solution for it.